# Failure to read properties from object passed from Java as a function argument?

Tags: nashorn

Try this and behold. This prints "undefined" then fails with *TypeError: [inner=java.lang.Object@159f197] has no such function "getBar"*

Now the problem here is that Nashorn should be able to access data bean properties with their names, without the need to call a function - like, a.b instead of a.getB(). This example, however, shows that this sort of access reads "undefined" instead of String value "localBar"; and the underlying function getBar() is not visible at all!
Thanks to the overridden toString(), the exception message proves that calling foo.getBar() from Java works fine.

What is happening?

```
import javax.script.Invocable;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;

public class NashornJS {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      ScriptEngineManager scriptEngineManager = new ScriptEngineManager();
      ScriptEngine scriptEngine = scriptEngineManager.getEngineByName("nashorn");

      final String localBar = "localBar";
      final Object foo = new Object() {
        public final String getBar() { return localBar; }
        @Override public String toString() { return "[inner="+getBar().toString()+"]"; }
      };

     try {
      scriptEngine.eval("function test(foo) { print(foo.bar); print(foo.getBar()); }");
      ((Invocable)scriptEngine).invokeFunction("test", foo);
     } catch (final ScriptException se) {
      se.printStackTrace();
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Interestingly, if I declare "normal" class Foo, Nashorn reads it properly. Unless I make Foo *private*. So I can suppose this problem has something to do with anonymous classes being nonpublic (though I cannot precisely guess why it has to be public; and, besides, JS actually *could* see the property, just could not read its value!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nashorn allows access only to public methods & public fields of public classes. As you guessed, the anonymous inner class is not public and hence Nashorn won't allow access to the same. Evaluating a non-existent property results in "undefined". That is consistent with JS language. And calling undefined as a function results in TypeError - which is again as per ECMAScript specification.

Comment: Actually public classes of "allowed packages" by current security policy. So, public methods of a public classes in sun.* package ("sensitive package") are not allowed.